# Angular: Pass object to directive

Tags: angular

I'm looking for a way to pass an object into a `directive`, but it turns up as a string.

Given this template:

```
<div my-directive="{ name: 'Roger', orders: ['apple', 'pie'] }"></div>
```

How can I get an object back in the directive?

```
@Input('my-directive') initialData: any; //initial data is a string
```

I assume maybe something with `JSON.parse`, but not sure how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use binding `[]` syntax

```
<div [my-directive]="{ name: 'Roger', orders: ['apple', 'pie'] }"></div>
```

otherwise it is treated a string, and you want object here.

Comment: Thank-you for reply. That object will never change, are there performance issues using property binding on objects that never change?

Comment: Surely there is, but it is rather neglectable.